# Android user interface with bitmaps problem

Tags: android, user-interface, layout, custom-view

I have a class Ball which extents View.Inside there i give some characteristics and implements onTouchEvent() so i can handle the movement.Also i use onDraw so i can draw the bitmap of the ball. in my activity class i crate a new Layout and i add the view to it so it can be displayed. Everything works fine except when, i try to add more balls to my layout they don't appear!Always the first added in layout ball is displayed!
Here's the onCreate code from activity class:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    int lHeight = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    int lWidth = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

    Point point1 = new Point();
    point1.x = 50;
    point1.y = 20;
    Point point2 = new Point();
    point2.x = 100;
    point2.y = 20;
    Point point3 = new Point();
    point3.x = 150;
    point3.y = 20;

    ColorBall ball1 = new ColorBall(this,R.drawable.bol_groen, point1);
    ll.addView(ball1, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(lHeight, lWidth));
    setContentView(ll);

    ColorBall ball2 = new ColorBall(this,R.drawable.bol_rood, point2);
    ll.addView(ball2, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(lHeight, lWidth));
    setContentView(ll);

    ColorBall ball3 = new ColorBall(this,R.drawable.bol_blauw, point3);

    ll.addView(ball3, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(lHeight, lWidth));
    setContentView(ll);        

}
```

What could possibly be the problem?I have try it also with only one setContentView() at the end.I am thinking that i can't use a Layout so i can draw bitmaps which are in a custom View!Am i right?
Should i change my code and create a View and inside there make an array with all the balls i want to be displayed and then set this View to be displayed from my main class of activity?(like this setContentView(customview)).

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `setContentView` several times, while it is expected to call only once per activity initialization.

**UPDATE**:

Could you use this layout xml instead of programmatic way you use? This is just to be 100% sure the container to which you will add the ColorBalls is Ok.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Just in case, here is the code to include it in the activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.your_name_of_layout);

    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
    ..
    container.addView(ball1);
    container.addView(ball2);
    ..
}
```

Comment: yes you are right but this isn't the problem,i have also try it with removing the setContentViews and holdonly the last one,but nothing changed.i still can't have all the balls drawn!

Comment: @stelios: another idea - try to change `ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);` to `ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);`

Comment: i have also tried this too...i'm thinking that i can't add more than one custom view in a layout....i know it doesn't sounds right but where is the problem?!!!!

Comment: @stelios: have you tried to only add `point3` - is it visible, and is it at the expected coordinates?

Comment: yes,i have tried this too and it works fine.if i have only one custom view added doesn't matter which one but only one it's ok....if you want i can add and the rest code!

Comment: @stelios: I am not 100% sure in correctness of the `LinearLayout ll` creation (because I always use xml for this). Please read my UPDATE section in the answer body.

Comment: I take a NullPointerException on the first addview line. i am not sure about this but i think that android it first creates the layout(so it's executing and all the addviews) and then runs everything else.If this is the way it's working then this is the answer to the NullPointerException that i take.I can't understand why something so simple...doesn't works....I think i have to go for a custom view so i can display my bitmaps....thanks @Arhimed!But if you ever find why this doesn't works please let me know;)

Comment: @stelios: you can get the reason of the NullPointerException looking at the log cat output. it should have the stack trace.

Comment: @Arhimed:yes,i took the reason from there and it was showing the line with the first addview...as i said above, if it's first creating the layout the exception is right because it tries to add to the layout the ball view which isn't initialized cause it's first try to add it and then run his constructor...